# How to replace specific tags that contains selected labels

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, tags

I wish to replace some specific spans with buttons, and the spans that I wish to replace has the same class names. How could I replace the spans (to  buttons) if they contains either of "apple" or "banana", but other spans with "orange" or "kiwi" I don't want to select?

From:

```
<span class=>
"kiwi"
</span>

<span class=>
"apple"
</span>

<span class=>
"orange"
</span>

<span class=>
"banana"
</span>
```

To:

```
<button>
"apple"
</button>

<button>
"banana"
</button>
```

Code:

```
function replaceElement (source, tagname) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var element = document.createElement(tagname);
    range.selectNodeContents(source);
    element.appendChild(range.extractContents());
    source.parentNode.replaceChild(element, source);
  }

var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span'), i;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
  replaceElement(document.querySelector('span'), 'button');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select an element based on the inner text. But what you can do is that you can filter the span element based on its inner text content.

```js
function replaceElement (source, tagname) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    var element = document.createElement(tagname);
    range.selectNodeContents(source);
    element.appendChild(range.extractContents());
    source.parentNode.replaceChild(element, source);
  }

var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span'), i;
for (i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
  if(spans[i].textContent.match('apple') ||spans[i].textContent.match('banana') ){
  replaceElement(spans[i], 'button');
  }
}
```

```html
<span class=>
"kiwi"
</span>

<span class=>
"apple"
</span>

<span class=>
"orange"
</span>

<span class=>
"banana"
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, that works really well! :) Would it be possible now to have "myFunction()" called on button click, and determine which button was clicked by its inner text?

Comment: yeah we can determine it