# Set click event for function to button

Tags: javascript, function, buttonclick

I have a button that I would like to assign a click event to, so that when I click on the button it will run the function.

`<button id="buttonid"></button>`

When I run the script below it will trigger the function, but the click event will not be added to the button. So I cannot use the button to trigger the function.

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello, world!");
}

var element = document.getElementById("buttonid");
element.onclick = myFunction;
```

I believe my goal would look like this:

`<button id="buttonid" onClick="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial code should work, provided that it is run after the DOM is ready so that the `document.getElementById("buttonid");` actually finds the element.

Check your console for errors that might indicate that `element` is `undefined`.

To make sure move the `script` tag that includes your code at the bottom (*right before closing the `body` tag*)

After the above a better approach is to not set the `onclick` attribute but instead use the `addEventListener` method.

```html
<body>

  <button id="buttonid">clickme</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      alert("Hello, world!");
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("buttonid");
    element.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Gabriele, thank you for your answer. I tried both your and my example above, and both actually works if I try to run them from console in Chrome here on stackoverflow. But at least my example above didn't work in Safari at work, and the DOM is ready, as I waited for the page to load before injecting the script from console, and the button id is also correct. In my case above, would it matter if 1. it's Safari browser, 2. injected by a script/extension or 3. the buttons are replaced spans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803268 you can read here where I replaced the spans with buttons

Comment: My end goal is to have the replaced spans (which are now buttons) clickable and have the same function assigned to all of them. The function will behave differently dependent on what is in the inner text of each button.

Comment: @JoeBerg It will not work with the code in that answer. You need to alter that script to maintain the `id` of the span to the button and run the code that adds the event handler **after** the code that replaces the spans.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Gabriele, that should have been the issue. I used the same method as in the other question to assign a new id to the buttons, and it worked now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  alert("Hello, world!");
  console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<button id="buttonid" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</button>
```

If you wanna add event handler from js code then that code should be included blow your html with button.